# UCITS ETF Capital Gains Taxes Different Depending on Stock Exchange?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, etf, capital-gains-tax, switzerland

If a certain UCITS ETF is domiciled in Ireland and is traded on both the Swiss SIX and London LSE exchanges (same ISIN but traded on both exchanges), will the tax implications (or broker’s automatic tax deductions) differ depending upon whether the trades occur on the LSE versus the SIX?

The prospective buyer of the ETF is neither a citizen nor resident of Ireland, the UK, or Switzerland.